# Making the view larger than the scrollbar

Tags: java, android, view, height, scrollbar

I'm trying to make a view whose height is independent of the scrollbar, where the view is larger than the scrollbar's height but is still accurately scrolled by said scrollbar.

An example of this would be the below image in a Harman infotainment system, in the settings menu:

[image: Harman Vehicle Settings]

As you can see from the above image, the scrollbar is slightly smaller than the total height of the view it scrolls for, which is normally not possible in something like a GridView or RecyclerView, since the height of the scroll bar is fixed to the height of the view. How would one achieve this with a GridView or RecyclerView? If not possible with a GridView or RecyclerView, how could I otherwise implement a similar idea?

Comment: Did you see this: https://androidopentutorials.com/android-vertical-scrollbar-styling/